# jQuery use RegEx from IFRAME contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, iframe

in iframe i'm loading external page and i want to use regex for get numeric . for example after loading iframe i have this content:

```
var urlToShow = 'http://my.site.com/go.php?user=454&code=3676ad29a406bc4461530d5a5859af43288bc3b9';
```

i want to get `code` value such as: `3676ad29a406bc4461530d5a5859af43288bc3b9` from that. how to access to iframe and get that with jQuery RegEx?

Comment: Could you share us your HTML?

Comment: @naota. thats popup window and only each ip can twice load page. i'm update post

Comment: Try using .contents() method - http://api.jquery.com/contents/ remember the same origin policy for iframe src

Comment: @Dipaks i want to use regex to get numerci after code from generated code into iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex to get the code value using the regex's search method:

```
/code=(\w+)/
```

The first captured group (`$1` or `\1`) will contain the code value.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/qP8rD0)

Comment: thanks. how to use that? `patt = new RegExp('/code=(\w+)/',text);` is not correct

Comment: this link can not help me and i can not get numeric after `code`